# D-modules and Algebraic Solutions of PDEs 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

I am not certain if this is a complete question and I fear it might be shot down. Anyway, I try to pose it. My question is in connection to  using D-modules to  study PDEs (and systems of PDEs). When I was doing a perusal on "A primer of algebraic D-modules by  S. C. Coutinho" the justification on the importance of D-modules; they provide an algebraic tool towards the solution of differential equations. This is the story I always hear!  Do someone have a reference or more information about D-modules and algebraically solution of PDEs ?.

Comment: It's probably worth fixing the typo in the title. Also, I think there is probably a D-modules tag, which would be appropriate.

Comment: May I say that the tag analysis-of-pde is inapropriate, since the purpose of D-modules is to bring an algebraic rather analytic point of view ?

Comment: There's the classic book by Borel *et al.*

Comment: Denis -- D-modules exist on complex analytic manifolds, not just on algebraic ones. Besides, the question explicitly asks for applications of D-modules to PDE's, so I think the PDE tag is appropriate here.

Comment: To be honest, the relevant chapter in Coutinho's book is pretty good. Borel et al is fairly heavy artillery, and more oriented towards technical stuff than providing intuition.

Comment: Algori yes, however, am very much interested in the algebraic ones! Ketil, true! this are the stories we always here that D-modules are geared towards providing an algebraic study to systems of PDEs do someone know people(research group) studying them using algebraic D-modules. I will be glad to know 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something deeper, but right there at the beginning of Hotta, Takeuchi, and Tanisaki's book on D-mods in the introduction is the connection to Linear PDEs.

I quote:

> Therefore, systems of linear partial differential equations can be identified with the
>   D-modules having some finite presentations like (0.0.3), and the purpose of the theory
>   of linear PDEs is to study the solution space HomD(M, O). Since the space
>   HomD(M, O) does not depend on the concrete descriptions (0.0.2) and (0.0.3) of
>   M (it depends only on the D-linear isomorphism class of M), we can study these
>   analytical problems through left D-modules admitting finite presentations. In the
>   language of categories, the theory of linear PDEs is nothing but the investigation
>   of the contravariant functor HomD(•, O) from the category M(D) of D-modules
>   admitting finite presentations to the category M(C) of C-modules.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly very nice. But apart from the Bernstein application mentioned in Paul Siegel's answer I haven't seen any other result about PDE's proved by the theory of D-modules.

Answer (score 12):

My guess is that this is a reference to Bernshtein's proof using the theory of D-modules that every constant coefficent partial differential operator $D$ has a fundamental solution, i.e. there is a distributional solution to the PDE $Du = \delta$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution.  This was an important theorem in analysis due to Malgrange and Ehrenpreis in the 1950's, and I think it came as a bit of a surprise that it can be done purely algebraically - all of the analytic input is encapsulated by a few basic facts about distributions.  Everyone knows that the fundamental theorem of algebra is proved in analysis class; maybe this means the fundamental theorem of analysis will one day be proved in algebra class!

Here is a link to Bernshtein's paper: http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/bernstein-mod-dif-FAN.pdf.  This was written in the 70's, and I think since then the argument has been cleaned up and made even more algebraic.

Comment: Nice paper indeed

Comment: If I am not mistaken, today there is a short proof of this result, since one can write down explicit Green functions for the general case.

Comment: Dear All. Would anyone be able to give a link to a more modern, shorter brushed version of the Bernstein proof?